# Custom field in XML with Views RSS module

Tags: views, feeds

I need to create an XML using Views RSS module, and it's created correctly. But I want to add a custom field to the XML. For example, an item from the XML is:

```
<item> 
<title>Liburu bat</title>
 <link>http://whatever.com/comercios/productos/1022/botak</link>
 <description>Produktu bat</description>
 <category>Forros para botas %% Espuelas %% Calzado</category>
 <guid isPermaLink="false">1022</guid>
 <source url="http://whatever.com/es/comercios/productos/whatever.xml">Escaparate Whatever</source>
</item>
```

And I want to add a custom field to that item, for example: 
Something else

Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `hook_views_rss_item_elements()` invocation if you're wanting to add a [custom item element](https://www.drupal.org/node/1346506). For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_rss_item_elements().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_rss_item_elements() {
  $elements['my_element'] = array(
    'title' => t('My Element'),
    'description' => t('Provides a my_element to an item element in Views RSS.'),
  );
  return $elements;
}
```

Comment: How would I do this in Drupal 8?? I tried using this same hook but it doesn't produce the custom node. I tried to search for the hook in Drupal 8 documentation but I couldn't find it. 

Thanx

Comment: Your feed format should be set to 'RSS Feed - Fields' not 'RSS Feed' if you want these hooks to be fired.