# How to add custom fields to views RSS so that feed must get validated?

Tags: 7, views, feeds

I have added 2 custom fields in Views RSS following below tutorials :

[Custom field in XML with Views RSS module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179764/custom-field-in-xml-with-views-rss-module)

https://www.drupal.org/node/1346506

I want to add namespace such as :

> Namespace:  Social
>
> Fields : social:facebook and social:soundcloud

Code used for above is :

```
function custom_views_rss_item_elements() {
  $elements['social:soundcloud'] = array(
    'title' => t('soundcloud'),
    'description' => t('Provides a soundcloud to an item element in Views RSS.'),
  );

  $elements['social:facebook'] = array(
    'title' => t('facebook'),
    'description' => t('Provides a Facebook to an item element in Views RSS.'),
  );

  return $elements;
}


function custom_views_rss_namespaces() {
  $namespaces['social'] = array(
    'prefix' => 'xmlns',
    'uri' => 'http://my.site', // tried passing http://base.google.com/ns/1.0
  );
  return $namespaces;
}
```

Fields get added in feeds but on validation with such as : https://validator.w3.org/feed/ get error such as **"Unexpected item "**

Please suggest how we can add custom fields and make them validated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought but maybe the uri should be "//s.bubb.1a" instead of http:// s.bubb.la

Comment: I think I need to define namespace url on site example http://www.feedforall.com/namespaces.htm such as iTunes have there own to define elements http://www.itunes.com/DTDs/Podcast-1.0.dtd